# understanding application of function: x > y - z & x < y + z

Tags: r, math

I am not particularly great with math and am trying to understand some R code. There is a function called "compareforequality" that looks like this:

```
compareforequality <- function(val1, val2, epsilon)
{
    val1 = as.numeric(val1);
    val2 = as.numeric(val2);
    equal = val1 > (val2 - epsilon) & val1 < val2 + epsilon;
    equal
}
```

where val1 and val2 are vector of numbers that signify timepoints (usually integers between -10 and 1000 that identify days in a time series), and epsilon is set to 1e-10. I can see that it will return true/false if the values are the same/different, but what is the application of a function like this instead of using something like identical(). What effect does the value of epsilon have on the comparison?

Thanks,

Comment: Things which are mathematically equal are not always numerically equal due to round-off error. `all.equal()` rather than `identical()` would be a built-in function replacement since `all.equal()` has an optional tolerance parameter.

Comment: These are probably better questions for the person that wrote the code. Perhaps they didn't know that `identical` exists or they just wanted to be more explicit about what they were doing.

Comment: (I'd think a clearer and simpler way to do that kind of comparison is `abs(val1 - val2) < epsilon`. I know you don't control it, but it's just another way to look at it.)

Comment: Ah I didn't think about rounding scenarios because the vectors should be integers but that makes sense. Thanks John.

MrFlick - Would of if I could of! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MrFlick, I suspect the use of `epsilon` is more closely modeled by `all.equal(..., tolerance=1e-10)`. dmb74, this is about *practical* equality, not necessarily *perfect* equality, and might be related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is not for them to be exactly equal, it's to compare for rough equality, as in "`val1` is within `epsilon` of `val2`".

The classic example of the usefulness of something like this is probably floating point numbers, where (for instance) `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`, but `0.1 + 0.2` is within `epsilon` of `0.3` for some small `epsilon`, which is quite often enough.

Comment: Oh ok, so if epsilon is e-10 than anything is equivalent as long as the numbers match to the 10th decimal. Thanks that helped me wrap my mind around it!